# SharePoint WSS3.0 how much free space should I be running with

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, hard-drive, wss-3.0

My Sharepoint WSS 3.0 box is running into various issues and I notice it has less that 3GB free HDD space.

what is the recommended amount for a sharepoint server to keep free and available?

This is a virtual system so I can easily assign more memory if required.

thanks,
Pierce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288751(office.12).aspx), the minimum is 3GB and recomended is 3GB + any space that you need for you database storage.

Comment: The database is on a separate box. This is the Minimum to deploy, what would you recommend for a running box?

Comment: From my experience, 2-3 GB is OK and I've never had problems with such amount of free space. I think you should look somewhere else to find a reason of your issues (what are they?)

Comment: Are you running Search Server Express for serving up search results or are you running with the native WSS Search?

Comment: Ill create a few separate Questions for the main issues I'm experiencing rather than clogging this question. thanks all!